# problems with invokings functions from module, using python3 and nltk

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

from the book: Natural Lenguage processing with Python, pg. 60.
I created a module with some functions (in EMACS) but when i run them with Python3 they give me problems.

```
 Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import nltk
>>>import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/home/giovanni/Scrivania/Giovanni/programmi")
>>> from esempio import unusual_words
>>> unusual_words(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words("austen-sense.txt"))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/home/giovanni/Scrivania/Giovanni/programmi/esempio.py", line 14, in unusual_words
    english_vocab = set((w.lower()) for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())
    NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined
```

why it says that nltk is not defined?

Comment: ``` def unusual_words(text):
   text_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in text if w.isalpha())
   english_vocab = set((w.lower()) for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())
   unusual = tect_vocab.difference(english_vocab)
   return sorted (unusual) ``` This is the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following statement to the top of esempio.py.

```
import nltk
```

Full file:

```
import nltk


def unusual_words(text):
    text_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in text if w.isalpha())
    english_vocab = set((w.lower()) for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())
    unusual = text_vocab.difference(english_vocab)
    return sorted(unusual)
```

Then issue the following commands in the python interactive shell. I copied them from your question.

```
import nltk
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/giovanni/Scrivania/Giovanni/programmi")
from esempio import unusual_words
unusual_words(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words("austen-sense.txt"))
```

Good luck!